# Exponent of a group

Tags: gr.group-theory

It is well known that every group of exponent $n=2$ is abelian. I remember having seen that this is also the case for $n=3$. (can someone give a proof). How does this generalize to any $n$ or to any prime $p$.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your claim about exponent 3. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31797/finite-groups-with-elements-of-order-n in particular the comments of Pete Clark and the answer of Francesco Polizzi

Comment: Your "exponent" is known as "order". There is not too much room for a group of 3 elements, say $e$, $a$ and $b$: you automatically get $ab=ba$...

Comment: Wadim, I don't follow. See the link in my comment and also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_%28group_theory%29

Comment: Wadim, "exponent" and "order" are not synonyms in finite group
theory. The order of a finite group is its cardinality, while
the exponent is the least $n$ with $x^n$ the identity for
all $x$ in the group.

Comment: The key word is "Burnside groups", you should easily find your answer in the literature by searching this.

Comment: The group $G$ of upper triangular matrices over $\mathbb{F}_3$ with diagonal $(1,1,1)$ is of exponent $3$.

Comment: In case my first comment wasn't clear: I think this is in effect a duplicate question, which is why I voted to close. Do people disagree?

Comment: This is *not* an exact dublicate. Here, only the property "abelian" is asked. 

Comment: Martin: he asks how "this" generalizes to higher exponent. The question I linked to asks: what can we say about finite groups of fixed exponent (save for the identity). I therefore see no reason for this question to remain open, especially when the Heisenberg example you give is given in the comments to that other question.

Comment: @Robin: thank you very much for refreshing my memory (I don't think I met the notion of "exponent" in the last 20 years!). Of course, with *exponent* 3 there is much room for noncommutativity! (But probably the author meant  "order"?!) @Yemon: you are extremely active in closing but not in clarifying to poor me what was wrong with my understanding. I was saved thanks to Robin. Since this isn't a homework, but an ordinary question, no reason (for me) to close. I recalled "exponent" from my childhood! :-)

Comment: @Wadim: I don't think the author meant "order" 3. There is only one group of order 3, namely Z/(3) which is pretty abelian...

Comment: @marwalix:  The result you "remember having seen" for n=3 _might_ have been Jacobson's result for rings, not groups.  See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29590/a-condition-that-implies-commutativity

Comment: @Armi: There is only one group up to isomorphism. :-) If the author means the exponent, then he can construct a nonabelian example by hand...

Comment: @Wadim...or check Alan's answer.

Comment: Wadim: I did not vote to close because this is a bad question. I voted to close because it seems to already have been answered by the comments and answers to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31797/finite-groups-with-elements-of-order-n

Comment: The result I have seen is that every finite group $G$ of exponent $3$ such as $3$ does not divide $o(G)$ is abelian.

Comment: @marwalix: For every finite group of exponent $3$, $3$ divides the order of $G$.  So what you say is true but vacuous.  @everybody: I am frankly surprised at the number of comments on this question: there's no research-level math issue here.  

Comment: @Pete L. Clark People generally like to comment a lot on the "easier questions" simply because it takes less time and effort not to mention that it also might get you free reputation points! 

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The group defined by $\langle x,y,z; x^3 = y^3 = z^3 = 1, yz = zyx, xy = yx, xz = zx\rangle$ has order 27, exponent 3 and is non-abelian.

(Checking exponent 3 basically comes down to ensuring that $(yz)^3 = (y^2z)^3 = (yx^2)^3 = 1$. Or by using Gap.)

Comment: See also the comments at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31797/finite-groups-with-elements-of-order-n

Comment: I should probably point out that this can be generalised to every $p>2$. That is, there always exists a group of order $p^{2n+1}$ with exponent $p$ such that $|Z(G)| = p$. Look up the classification of Extra-special $p$-groups for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Well, any finitely generated group G of exponent 3 is finite by a classical theorem of Burnside. And since the order of every element is 3, the order of G must be a power of 3 by Cauchy's theorem. It follows that G is a finite nilpotent group. A similar argument shows that
the same is true for any finitely generated group of exponent 4. This is unknown for 5, and false for 6.

Correction: it seems (see the answer of Primoz above) that any group of exponent 3 is nilpotent, altough it can be infinite if it not finitely generated.

Comment: See also the comments at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31797/finite-groups-with-elements-of-order-n

Answer (score 5):

Every group of exponent 3 is nilpotent of class at most 3, and this bound is best possible. The question whether finitely generated groups of exponent $n$ are finite is also known as the [Burnside problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_problem). There is an excellent historical [overview](http://www-gap.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/HistTopics/Burnside_problem.html) of this problem, along with a list of relevant references.

Answer (score 1):

The result I have seen is that every finite group $G$  of exponent $3$  such as $3$  does not divide $o(G)$  is abelian.

It generalises the following way : every n-abelian group (such as $(xy)^n=x^n y^n$) that has got no element (other than $1$) whose order divides $n(n-1)$ is abelian. One can refer to J.L Alperin A classification of n-abelian groups in Canadian Journal of Mathematics (1969)

Comment: I do not understand the sentence "every finite group $G$ of exponent $3$ such as $3$ does not divide $o(G)$". If $G$ is a finite group of exponent $3$ then it has order $3^n$, and so $3$ divides $o(G)$, so no groups satisfy this condition. Right? (I realise this is over 10 years old, so sorry for dredging it up!)